# Spaces between elements in HAML

Tags: haml

How would you represent this in HAML?:

```
<a>Link</a> | <a>Link</a>
```

Note that I want to *retain* the spaces on either side of the bar.

Comment: I think you should try it with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write exactly what you've written, which is perfectly valid HAML. You may embed regular HTML into HAML:

```
%h1
  <a>Link</a> | <a>Link</a>
```

Sometimes whitespace bites you when you're marking things up with HAML, and there is no pretty way of making your tags come out correctly. That is why HAML gives you the option of falling back to HTML.

Note that, if you're ok with one *or more* spaces between your links and the `|`, you can just write regular old HAML:

```
%h1
 %a link
 |
 %a link
```

The new lines will be preserved, and render as a space in the browser, where any amount of any kind of whitespace will always be treated like a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Put '|' on next line, new line will be preserved, and render as a white space.

```
%a link
|
%a link
```

Answer (score 1):

meagar's answer is how I would do it, you could also use haml filters to write exactly the HTML you need.
This might sound dirty, but filters use is encouraged, see this article : http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/